# How to deploy web service on Docker container

Tags: macos, tomcat, docker, boot2docker

This is my Dockerfile:

```
#Build java web app container image
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER wangyao
#Make java and tomcat install directory
RUN mkdir /usr/local/java
RUN mkdir /usr/local/tomcat
#Copy jre and tomcat into image
ADD jdk1.8.0_45.jdk /usr/local/java/
ADD apache-tomcat-7.0.62 /usr/local/tomcat/
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/Contents/Home
CMD cd /usr/local/tomcat;./bin/catalina.sh run
#Expose http port
EXPOSE 8080
```

Then i built it and try to start it:

```
wangyaos-MBP-3:flexcloud wangyao$ ls
Dockerfile      apache-tomcat-7.0.62    jdk1.8.0_45.jdk
wangyaos-MBP-3:flexcloud wangyao$ docker build -t flexcloud .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 355.6 MB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
........
Successfully built 1f824d246b39
wangyaos-MBP-3:flexcloud wangyao$ docker run -i -t flexcloud
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/java/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:        /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
/usr/local/java/Contents/Home/bin/java: 20: /usr/local/java/Contents/Home/bin/java: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
wangyaos-MBP-3:flexcloud wangyao$
```

what does `word unexpected  (expecting ")")` mean ?

I used `$ ./bin/catalina.sh run` without docker,  and I can run it,  but i why can not run it on the docker container ?

Comment: That looks more like a shell script error. Is `/usr/local/java/Contents/Home/bin/java` actually the java executable? It's an unusual location to set `JAVA_HOME`. Maybe that file is actually a shell script named `java`  containing a syntax error

Comment: i can sure that the `/usr/local/java/Contents/Home/bin/java`  is correct

Comment: So if you gain access to your container (with `docker exec -it <CONTAINER>  bash`) and execute `/usr/local/java/Contents/Home/bin/java -version` it's all OK?

Comment: Oh,  java -version does not work,  i had discovered that jdk set uncorrectly !   thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the error `Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")` is a shell script error, which implies that `/usr/local/java/Contents/Home/bin/java` is not actually the java executable.

Accessing the container with `docker exec -it <container> bash` and executing `/usr/local/java/Contents/Home/bin/java -version` shows us whats actually going on, as per @KingOfSocket's comment.